# Should I use inetd or xinetd?

Tags: services, xinetd, inetd

I see openbsd-inetd is installed by default but there are quite a few mentions of xinetd in AskUbuntu.

I have a custom service to install. inetd would provide all the features I need.
Should I be using inetd or xinetd to be most compatible with future updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xinetd if it does what you want, but personally you should avoid using inet at all. Some information on the service itself would help answer your question.

Comment: Hi Strings, we have an inhouse developed system that facilitates unix to pc communications. Ie send a Unix file to the PC of the domain user who logged in to the Unix server and many other things. When the PC boots, it connects to the Unix server on a specific tcp port and runs a Linux process that takes care of all the communication between Linux and the PC. It maps the Windows user to a Linux user.

Comment: Hi Strings, Er, you seem to be contradicting yourself. In the first post you said use inetd, then in your last post, you said (there is a typo you might like to correct, I think), use xinetd. Openbsd-inetd is inetd, not xinetd. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I did mean xinted, sorry I used the general term, I should have been more specific. I only suggest xinetd vs openbsd-inetd. because you know it will do exactly what you want. imo openbsd-inetd is just the default inet, nothing wrong with using something else.