# How to start vnc server on-demand (not on boot)

Tags: vnc, xinetd, inetd

I have a vps which has the basic xfce environment & tightvncserver installed.

I would like to have tightvncserver automatically start whenever I initiate a connection to the port it runs on (in my case, `5901`).

I've seen posts about using `inetd` or `xinetd` to do this, but I've also seen lots of posts saying that (x)inetd is not included in Ubuntu for a reason, and that it's a bad idea to use it.

Anyways, I'm looking for a way to **auto-start tightvncserver whenever there's an incoming connection to port 5901, preferably with as few dependencies as possible**

Comment: *In general* using inetd or xinetd is indeed a bad idea, but that's like saying that *in general* it is a bad idea to use a nail gun. Yet for certain jobs, it's the right tool. The main issue is performance. Launching a new process for every connection is an extremely slow process.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why is *"bad idea using xinetd or inetd"*. I checked both bug tracker and didn't saw any security issue.

That said, I will try to repeat what you already have found about configuring 'xinetd':

`xinetd` is pretty straight forward to configure. It uses the `/etc/xinetd.d/` directory to store all the per-service configuration, so you only need to create the configuration to start `tightvncserver`, a `sudo vim /etc/xinetd.d/tightvncserver` to create a file, then insert your configuration (this can be modified according to your needs):

```
service tightvncserver
{
        socket_type     =  stream
        protocol        =  tcp
        wait            =  no
        ## I don't run a vnc server myself, but you should change this for the user your VNC service uses.
        user            =  root
        port            =  5901
        server          =  /usr/sbin/tightvncserver
        ## This allows access from anyone in the 192.168 subnet, if you want anyone, just do not add this line.
        only_from       =  192.168.0.0
        log_on_failure  += USERID
        disable         =  no
}
```

That's all. Now you should disable boot up of the `tightvncserver` in the rc-d directories.

There are more options you can add to this, but I shall leave that to the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/xinetd.conf.5.html).

Comment: That's quite helpful if I decide to go the xinetd route. I just stumbled across the built-in xinetd replacement the Ubuntu ships with, Upstart. I'm going to see if I can get the desired functionality from Upstart's [socket events](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/socket-event.7.html).

Comment: Also, here is an [example](http://askubuntu.com/questions/237931/should-i-use-inetd-or-xinetd) of the kind of negativity towards (x)inetd I've been seeing on this site and the Ubuntu forums. Not sure if it's warranted or not, but there are definitely a number of people who don't think it's a good idea to use (x)inetd.

Comment: @QRohlf he just says to avoid inetd **not xinetd**: *"you should avoid using inet at all"*

Comment: Ah. That makes a lot more sense - the other two places I saw inetd being knocked, it was inetd and not xinetd as well. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Despite finding basically this exact same recipe in 4 or 5 other places on the Internet, it doesn't work at all for me.  tightvncserver just hangs when a client connects.

Comment: @Glyph [try slm answer.](http://askubuntu.com/a/473440/169736)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try and use `tightvncserver` I would attempt to the same thing that @Braiam's suggested but with Xvnc instead.

```
service Xvnc
{
        disable = no
        type = UNLISTED
        socket_type = stream
        protocol = tcp
        user = nobody
        wait = yes
        server = /usr/bin/Xvnc
        server_args = -inetd :1 -query localhost -geometry 1024x768 -depth 16 -NeverShared -once -rfbauth /root/.vncpasswd
        port = 5901
}
```

You can adjust where the password file lives by changing this bit above: `/root/.vncpasswd`. The permissions on that file can be squirrelly so you might need to make them `chmod 600 .vncpasswd`.

If you need further details take a look at the tutorial, [2. Launching VNC server using xinetd](http://www.styryx.com/en/computers/operating-systems/unix-linux/remote-desktop-connection-on-linux-vnc-server-xinetd-and-xdmcp/2-launching-vnc-server-using-xinetd) that shows many different ways that you can run VNC as a `xinetd` service.

#### Using xinetd

The entire commentary on not using xinetd is bunk. It's a perfectly fine service to use and just as everything else, you need to understand the implications of using technology X, nothing more.